# How to fix nginx conf for static site?

Tags: nginx, nginx-location

I don't understand why my nginx.conf file does not work.

This is just supposed to serve a static web site.

Later I want to add a wordpress to /blog.

Currently I want to make the main static site work.

The related conf is this:

```
  location / {
    index index.html
    root /var/www/html/xlanding;
    try_files $uri $uri/ =406;
  }
```

This nginx is dockerized. I log in to the docker container and I can confirm that /var/www/html/xlanding/ exists and there is an index.html file there.

When I visit the url I see a 406 error (just changed from 404 to confirm that block is entered). So the block is matched.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Ah, I missed a semicolon after the "index index.html".